# Multibarchart nplot r studio

Tags: r, title, program-entry-point, axis, names

I need help with my multibarchart, how can I change and add names to the axis? My code looks like:

```
Sexeye = as.data.frame(sexeyes) 
p2a<-nPlot(Freq~Sex, group='Eye', data=Sexeye, type= 'multiBarchart') p2a$chart(color=c('brown', 'black', 'yellow', 'blue')) 
p2a$addFilters("Sex", "Eye") p2a$set(dom='chart3', width=600) 
p2a
```

How can I add a title and names for the axis and also for each group and bar?